# Random forest (rfsrc) not reproducible despite setting seed

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I am not able to reproduce my Random Forest `rfsrc` results despite setting a seed.  Each time I run the code below I see a different ordering to variables listed by order of importance.

```r
set.seed(415)
fit1sjl <- rfsrc(Social_Jetlag_Comp ~ ., data=df, importance="permute", 
    ntree=2000)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?  If it helps the overall variance explained (OOB estimate) is very low.

Comment: Some programs use their own internal random number generators.  This is a matter of consulting with the documentation or, if that's silent, looking at the code.  `rfsrc` is not part of base `R`, anyway.

Comment: We cannot reproduce your example, but `library(randomForestSRC); set.seed(415);` `fit1<-rfsrc(Surv(time,status)~.,data=veteran,ntree=100,importance="permute")` seems to produce similar results each time I run it

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I looked at the documentation and tried setting the seed from within the call ```fit1sjl <- rfsrc(Social_Jetlag_Comp ~ ., data=df, importance="permute", ntree=2000,seed=415)``` but this still gives me slightly different results each time.  Can I expect to set a seed that will return exactly the same result each time it is run (mainly interested in ordering of variable importance here) or is that asking too much of RF?